# If a JavaScript function returns a promise, can I make it async instead of using try/catch clauses in the function?

Tags: javascript, promise, try-catch

I have a function that may throw exceptions. On successful execution my function will return a promise. I want to handle any function exceptions or a promise rejection the in the same catch block later in the code.

I could add a try block in the function and on any caught exception return a rejected promise, e.g.

```
function foo(x) {
  try {
    // code here may throw an exception
    return myPromise(x.y)
  }
  catch (ex) {
    return Promise.reject(ex)
  }
}
```

I can then use `foo(x).catch(ex => { /* handler here */})`

Alternatively I could make the function async, resulting in any function exceptions producing a `foo()` promise rejection, e.g.

```
async function foo(x) {
    // code here may throw an exception
    return myPromise(x.y)
}
```

I can handle exceptions and rejections as before. Is there any drawbacks in the second approach?

Comment: You should definitely use the second method as it's shorter and does the same thing.

Comment: The second is sometimes confusing when it's not obvious that the code might throw exceptions and that you *want* them to become promise rejections, but otherwise it's totally fine.